# Checking Topology using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, topology

I have two Shapefiles with Polygons ( City and Forerst)

Is there a Plugin who is able check the topology (QGIS)?

Like "Knots do not overlap" or something like that. I dont want that they overlap.

Answer (score 12):

The new **Topology Checker Plugin** will be available in the next release. You can see it at work in this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huhkTZkoKC8

More info: https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/pull/356

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [GRASS Toolbox](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/QGIS_GRASS_Cookbook#Example%3a_Cleaning_of_topology_of_a_SHAPE_file_using_the_GRASS_Toolbox) for that.

> **Cleaning of topology of a SHAPE file using the GRASS Toolbox**
>
> 1. Load the SHAPE file into QGIS
> 2. Use existing GRASS mapset (or create a new one) with matching projection settings
> 3. Now you have to transfer the SHAPE file from QGIS to GRASS using Toolbox -> File management -> Import into GRASS -> Import vector into
>      GRASS -> Import vector into GRASS from QGIS view (v.in.ogr.qgis). Some
>      topological problems may be reported depending on the quality of your
>      SHAPE file.
> 4. These topological problems we can fix now in GRASS via toolbox using the topology tools: Vector -> Develop map -> Toolset for
>      cleaning topology of vector map -> v.clean.break.  Define a threshold
>      in map units (for example 0.5 [m] or likewise). Analyse the printed
>      report, probably the threshold needs to be adjusted or a different
>      topology cleanup tool to be used. Click then on view output to show
>      the result as map.
> 5. Export the cleaned map to SHAPE format: File management -> Export from GRASS -> Export vector from GRASS -> v.out.ogr