# QGIS 2.4.0: dissolve tool renders artifacts / errors

Tags: qgis, dissolve

The dissolve tool (vector>geoprocessing tools>dissolve) renders some artifacts on shapes with high number of polygons. I’m using a [shapefile](http://www.dgterritorio.pt/ficheiros/cadastro/caop/caop_download/caop_2014_0/contaadcaop2014) with 3222 polygons and I’m trying to dissolve it using the field “municipio”, but when the dissolve tool ends calculating the new shape has some artifacts

[image]

Does anyone had a similar problem? How to work around it?

I’ve also used v.dissolve from GRASS and the dissolve polygon from SAGA, but the problem persists.
I’ve used the same shapefile on ArcGIS 9.3 with the dissolve tool. None artifact/error was produced.

**Edit 1**

I'm trying to use the v.clean tool as sugested by WhiteboxDev. However I'm getting this error:

> An error has occured while executing Python code:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ProcessingToolbox.py",
>   line 181, in executeAlgorithm   File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py",
>   line 511, in checkBeforeOpeningParametersDialog   File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py",
>   line 361, in checkGrass7IsInstalled   File
>   "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 96, in join
>   TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
>
> QGIS version:
>   2.4.0-Chugiak Chugiak, 8fdd08a
>
> Python path:
>   ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing',
>   'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python',
>   u'C:/Users/CERCOTRICHAS/.qgis2/python',
>   u'C:/Users/CERCOTRICHAS/.qgis2/python/plugins',
>   'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\bin\python27.zip',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\DLLs',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\bin',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\GDAL-1.11.0-py2.7-win32.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode',
>   'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools',
>   'C:\Program Files\SpiderOak\shell_extension_lib\shared.zip']

Not entirely sure if this error is QGIS related...
Any idea why I'm getting this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: I second WhiteboxDev opinion, this is related to the data itself. The reason why ArcGIS does not produce any errors is because it uses an internal tolerance to snap nearby vertices.

Comment: Check this answers https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71612/dissolve-polygons-in-qgis-geos-with-tolerance

Answer (score 3):

This is likely the result of topological errors in your shapefile. You need to run a vector cleaning function, like the **v.clean** tool in the GRASS plugin to repair your topology before running **Dissolve**.

Comment: yep, that is just what it looks like.

Comment: @usertwoseventwothreenine user two, I can't tell you how many times I've seen this pattern myself and think afterwards, 'I need to clean my topology!' You'd think I'd eventually remember to do it beforehand ;)