# Detecting gaps in polyline using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, topology, gap

I'm making routes by selecting links from a streets layer which I export as a new temporarely layer in ArcMap 10.0 with an ArcView/Basic level license. This layer which I call route_temp unfortunately can be very long and contain gaps, for instance when i forget to select very small links which are difficult to see because they are overlaid by other layers. But sometimes the route contains gaps which have to be there because a cluster is in between it. What I would like to be able of is to visiualize all the gaps in the route, so that I can judge myself which gaps have to be filled and which gaps have to stay in the route.

Do you know a tool for this, maybe a field calculator script or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you had ArcEditor/Standard or ArcInfo/Advanced, you could use a [topology](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_topology_in_ArcGIS/006200000001000000/) to check for gaps and dangles.  If not, there are some [open source tools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34415/how-to-check-topology-in-qgis) available that accomplish the same thing.  What a topology does is examine your data for violations of rules that you supply it with, identifies them, and helps you correct them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little shot in the dark, but you could use XTools to make points at the start and end of your polyline layer.  With the point layer that will be created you could run a distance matrix to calculate the distance from each point to the others.  The values will be in distances.  There will be zeros (when they are snapped) and large values (when there are far lines).  The values in between zero and the large number would be the gaps between the polylines.  This approach will allow you to zoom to the specific gap, using the point file.